# How much i pay when use onSnapshot firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So when i read realtime data use onSnapshot in collection with 1000 document, i will pay for 1000 read for first time i render the page.

Nah my question is, when someone add 1 new document to that collection, am i get charged only for read 1 new document or i get charged again for read 1000 document + 1 new document ?

I read some post on this site about that, and also i read from firebase website in link below but i not really understand.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens

This post

**Listening to query results**

> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get
> realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
> also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
> because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
> deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: when someone adds 1 new document to that collection, am I get charged only for read 1 new document or I get
> charged again for read 1000 document + 1 new document ?

The answer is to be found in the second paragraph of the documentation excerpt you mention in your question:

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated.

Listening to an entire collection is totally equivalent to listening to a query (the [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) class extends the [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#query_class) class), therefore when someone adds a new document to the collection, **you are charged only for one document read**.